# How can I assign aliases and remove them in GNOME Do?

Tags: gnome-do

I'm interested in using GNOME Do's Alias feature. I can't find any information about how to use it, though.

How can I assign aliases and how can I remove them in GNOME Do?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**This is a description of how it *should* work; I don't regularly use the Alias action, and it seems to be broken for me at the moment. I'll update this answer after it's fixed...**

To assign an alias you just need to select the object you want to alias, the ‘Assign Alias’ action, and then the alias you'd like to assign in the third pane.

For example, after hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the image below...

[image: Screenshot of Assign Alias action]

I'll have a new item called “The Twitts” that aliases to the Friends item.

Comment: Hey, thank you. Seems like it's broken on my system (Xubuntu 14.04) as well.